# Why does my Brother labeler say both 9.5V and 12V?

Tags: voltage, adapter

First time poster on this SE. Thanks for existing!

I have a Brother PT2600 labeler and it says 9.5V DC IN on the adapter socket. I tried with a 9V adapter and it doesn't power on. 0.5V shouldn't make a difference, right?

On the back of the device it says DC 12V 12W. And it also accepts 8 AA batteries, with 8x1.5V = 12V.

Why would it list two voltages? Is there something about battery voltage that is different than adapter voltage? If it really takes 8 AA batteries in series then I should be able to use a 12V DC adapter, right?

Comment: A 9.5 V power adapter will always supply 9.5 V (assuming it is a properly regulated one). Alkaline AA batteries are 1.5 V when they're new and unused. When you discharge these batteries, the voltage will drop so a good design should still work when the batteries are 1.2 V. Also rechargeable batteries have this lower voltage. It can also be that the 9 V adapter cannot provide the current needed by the labeler. It can also be that the polarity is different and a diode blocks the power. A device working on 9.5 V but not 9 V seems an odd design choice.

Comment: Do be careful of DC polarity - some devices have reversed-polarity plugs/jacks.

Answer (score 1):

First, the two voltages determine a range, not two separate operating voltages. Anything between the two voltages, such as 10.4 volts, will also work. Why 9.5 is specified is something of a mystery, since the Brother AC adapter recommended is only rated at 9 volts.

Also, I suspect your problem is quite simple - your 9 volt adapter either is not working, or your connector is the wrong polarity. For this purpose, the + voltage should be on the outer contact, and the inner should be the -.  It is also possible that your adapter simply does not provide enough current. The Brother AC adapter is rated for 1.6 amps, so if you're using something significantly wimpier than this, particularly since your voltage is at the bottom of the operating range, that it is being pulled down to the point that the unit doesn't operate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The polarity does seem to be correct based on the labels, and the one I have is rated at 2A. So not sure. Could just be a junk unit. My next inclination is to try a 12V adapter as long as there is no risk of frying the thing...